# tools for displaying custom performance counters across multiple machines

Tags: wmi, performancecounter

I want to monitor the performance of my application.

I wrote custom performance counters and monitored them with perfmon but since my application run on several machines I need a tool (open source ?) which can monitor the whole system (aggregate the same counters across the different machines, user-friendly display, graphs and so on).

On way to do so is to query the performance counter on all the machine using WMI and display the result with graphs and more I’m sure there are several solution for that and I would like to hear about them.

Thanks,

Ron Anavi

Comment: What is programming language of your application? What OS are supported  (Unix, Linux, OSX, Windows). What processor architecture? @skb, please, give some comments...

Comment: The application is a .NET app.  OS=Windows

Comment: @animuson: can you recommend another stack exchange site to put this on?